# Answer to message if sent within a period of time

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm setting up a discord bot for a server which has a rule for no chatting between 23-06. I want the bot to answer to *every* (except itself of course) message sent within that time period.

I know I have to use

```
if (msg.author.bot) return
    else if (msg.createdAt ===/*what here?*/)
```

but I have absolutely no idea how would the time be formatted

````
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    if (msg.author.bot) return
        else if (msg.createdAt === /*something*/) {
        embed
            .setColor(randomHexColor())
            .setThumbnail('')
            .addField('test')
            .setFooter('test')
        return msg.channel.send(embed)
    }
});```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createdAt` for discord messages is a standard javascript `Date` object. As such, you can relatively easily use all associated functions on it to do what you want.

In your case, you're interested in `getHours()`. This returns the integer hours (0-23). So, if you want no chatting between 23-6, you'll be doing this:

```
else if (msg.createdAt.getHours() >= 23 || msg.createdAt.getHours() < 6) {
```

Do note that the `>=` could've easily been replaced by `===`, I it is purely there to remind you of what you set out to do for the next time you go over the code: **after** 23:00 :-)

Comment: And what about timezones? No clue about goe discord handles this (is it.run on server?) but sounds a bit like half of the world cant talk to the other half ;D

Comment: Good point. What timezone is your restriction on? I assumed the bot was running in local time. Discord's websocket (which is where your messages come from) are timestamped clearly as UTC, and the `Date` object will seamlessly make the transition between that and local time for `getHours()`. If you want to change the timezone, you'll need to use `getUTCHours()` instead, and then convert from UTC to something else (using a library like moment.js is great for this).

Comment: Thank you, that worked. But how would I change the presence of the bot at that time without a message triggering the change? getHours() doesn't work on its own.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "change the presence of the bot *at that time*"?

Comment: I'm with @cloud on this one, your question does not show any of the networking or presence part of your code. How can we even assume what you are doing?

Comment: Change its presence at 23:00 to "active" or something like that and change it back to "inactive" at 06:00. By presence I mean the "playing" message, as it's "client.user.setPresence()". I want the message to change immediately when it's 23:00, not when some trigger, e.g. message triggers the event. I basically need a clock that triggers an event at certain time.@cloud @Sébastien Renauld.  

Example: https://hastebin.com/wodujeveso.js

Comment: do the presence change in another, separate part of your bot. Use [node-process](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) to trigger it.